# Flutter arabic letters not showing the correct color when using .withOpacity

Tags: flutter, colors, arabic, letter

Using Colors.white.withOpacity(0.25) on Arabic letters doesn't look the same as using the same color on English letters.
The color opacity on the Arabic letters doesn't seem to cover all the letters, some parts of some letters have the full white opacity.

Is there a known fix for this issue?

Flutter version 1.20.3

This is a simple code snippet for the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48Cpj.png)

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Align(
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          color: Colors.black,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                "أحرف العربية",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 60.0,
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.25),
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                "English letters",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 60.0,
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.25),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can yo provide us the Image with the problem.
that you are attached doesn't show the error  .

Comment: There isn't an error, the Arabic letters' opacity color is not covering all of the letters